# How do you know what's returned by a method when the MSDN doesn't show it?

Tags: c#, .net

Okay the title is very confusing I know. So let me explain what I mean by an example:

(I've got the example from the book that I'm reading, which is "Pro C# with .NET and .NET Core)

```
public void RegisterWithCarEngine(CarEngineHandler methodToCall)
{ 
    if (listOfHandlers == null)
        listOfHandlers = methodToCall;
    else
       listOfHandlers = Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall) as CarEngineHandler;
}
```

`listOfHandlers` is an instance of the delegate `CarEngineHandler`. 
My question is specifically about this line:

```
listOfHandlers = Delegate.Combine(listOfHandlers, methodToCall) as CarEngineHandler;
```

You see here that I'm calling the static method `Combine()`. And you see that I'm casting it to `CarEngineHandler`. Therefore this method returns an instance of `CarEngineHandler` treated as `Delegate`.

But here's what is confusing me. How do I know that it's returning an instance of `CarEngineHandler` when the MSDN doesn't say that?

All that the [MSDN says about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771(v=vs.110).aspx) is this:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: [System.Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   A new delegate with an invocation list that concatenates the invocation lists of the delegates in the `delegates` array. Returns `null` if `delegates` is `null`, if `delegates` contains zero elements, or if every entry in `delegates` is `null`.

Comment: @zackraiyan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1eh4771(v=vs.110).aspx ? MSDN is much more than a forum.

Comment: You are casting the result of the Combine method as a CarEngineHandler. At runtime, the Delegate instance can be an instance of CarEngineHandler... or some other kind of delegate, in which cas listOfHandlers can be null.

Comment: Since `listOfHandlers` is `CarEngineHandler` and `methodToCall` is `CarEngineHandler` - what else combine can return?

Comment: @Evk With `public delegate void CarEngineHandler(CarEngine carEngine);` as an example, there appears to be nothing in the documentation that actually promises the result won't be canonicalised to `Action<CarEngine>`.

Answer (score 4):

You're completely right that this is something that should be documented. It's sort of implied by the fact that all delegates are required to be of the same type (as documented under "Exceptions"), but that doesn't actually promise anything. It's also required by "Combine is useful for creating event handlers that call multiple methods each time an event occurs." but that doesn't actually promise anything either.

Unfortunately, this is just one of those cases where you can tell from the fact that MS themselves rely on `Delegate.Combine` behaving this way that it isn't ever going to change.